# Client Executable path from webservice

Tags: web-services

I have a webservice which my windows application use as "Service Reference"

My program has more than 1500 clients and all clients calling same exe file (such as **\\myserver\c$\myapp\myapp.exe**)

I want to add a control into my webservice functions for check client executable path and i prevent calling a function when executable path is different than **\\myserver\c$\myapp\myapp.exe**

maybe

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function DoSomething() as string
   if GetClientExePath <> "\\myserver\c$\myapp\myapp.exe" then 
      return nothing
   else
      return "helloooooo"
   endif

end function

public function GetClientExePath()
    return clientexepath
end Function
```

i can get client IP adress. But as i said we have more than 1500 clients i can't store their ip adresses.

Thanks inadvance.

Comment: You mean you want your web service to know the path of whatever called it's method?

Comment: yes exactly. my program working on local intranet. i want to prevent calling my webservice from another exe file.  because all local intranet users can reach my webservice. someone can code another program and use my webservice. i dont want to this.

Comment: I've never heard of being able to do that. Usually you would add authentication to the service to ensure only recognized users access it. But if it's local, you're worried about other users within your network accessing the service?

Comment: yes. other users can access service on internet explorer or another windows program. i dont want to  this.